# Populating Spinner from SQLite database using CursorAdapter

Tags: android, sqlite, android-widget

I've looked at similar questions but they don't explain how to use a CursorAdapter.

What I'm trying to do is populate a Spinner with a column of Strings read from a selected database.

This is my current code:

```
//open database depending on selected item
myDatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("Courses"+spSem.getSelectedItem().toString(),MODE_PRIVATE,null);


//read fields to be populated and store them in an arraylist, I need to use arraylist since not every database has the same size
Cursor resultSet = myDatabase.rawQuery("Select * from Subject",null);
resultSet.moveToFirst();
List<String> course = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 1; i < course.size(); i++) {
    course.add(resultSet.getString(i));
}
```

This next part is where I'm stuck, I'm thinking I need to use CursorAdapter() to populate the spinner, but I have no idea how? Previously I had this:

```
   String[] cArr = new String[course.size()];
    course.toArray(cArr);
    CursorAdapter a = new CursorAdapter(this,cArr,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    a.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spCourse.setAdapter(a);
```

With this code I get the error "CursorAdapter is abstract and cannot be instantiated", and "cannot resolve method'setDropDownView'".

Comment: Populating Spinner from SQLite DB does not strongly required Cursor Adapter. You can use BaseAdapter, ArrayAdapter also.

The Cursor must include a column named "_id" or this class will not work. Additionally, using MergeCursor with this class will not work if the merged Cursors have overlapping values in their "_id" columns.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html

Comment: @AshishTiwari How would I use BaseAdapter or ArrayAdapter in my case? I previously tried using ArrayAdapter but got stuck when I realised you can't dynamically add an Array to resources

Comment: you can get records from DB  in an ArrayList, and then you can populate spinner from arrayList. No need to use fixed size array.